# Discord.py trying to found out all the "bot.wait_for" type str like "message" and "button_click"

Tags: python, discord

I just started making a discord bot in python and I can't found what exactly I should write here (see the code), if anyone can show me a table with all the possibility thanks. ( I'm mostly looking for one that wait a select option ).
Exemple:

```
#What I know:
res = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
res = await bot.wait_for("message")
#What I want to do:
res = await bot.wait_for("when a option is select")
```

Right know I only know "message", "button_click", is there a way to create a custom wait_for ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [discord.py Event Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#event-reference)

It lists every possible event in vanilla discord.py.

But given you're using discord-components they add additional events, namely: `"button_click"` and `"select_option"`. [2](https://gitlab.com/discord.py-components/discord.py-components/-/blob/master/discord_components/interaction.py#L14)

You can check out usage of `"select_option"` in [lib's examples](https://gitlab.com/discord.py-components/discord.py-components/-/blob/master/examples/example_cog.py#L67)

Comment: Thank you that's what I wanted.